# The meaning of verb 'strain'

Tags: word-meaning

> She listens to her great-uncle’s footfalls across the ceiling, and his
>   voice—310 1467 507 2222 576881—and then her grandfather’s song, “Clair
>   de Lune,” **strains** over her like a blue mist.

From *All the Light We Cannot See* by Anthony Doerr

Does '**strain**' here mean '**ooze**'?

Comment: What's with the random chunk of numbers? Is this actually part of the quote? Also, see the music-related definition of strain.

Comment: The random chunk of numbers are secret codes the great uncle passes onto allies using a radio transmitter. After the radio transmission, he plays a record of classic music for a minute.

Comment: @Varun KN  are you saying 'strain' here is a noun? I thought in the sentence 'Her grandfather’s song strains over her like a blue mist.', 'strain' acts as a verb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that the author uses *strain* as a verb here, with the meaning *plays* or *sounds*.

There's a long history of the noun and verb forms borrowing from each other. And there are many many words in English that are both nouns and verbs.  There is an obsolete verb meaning that refers to *playing* an instrument or singing a song. Here the verb is intransitive. EDIT: please see my note at the end of the answer, regarding the obsolete verb *strain*.

The noun *strain* can refer to

> A strain is also a particular sound:
>
> *Strains of piano music drifted across the room.*

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/strain)

Note the example sentence of Cambridge refers to the *strains* (sound) of piano music. Compare this to a definition in [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/strain):

> The sound of a piece of music.

So, simply put, the author uses the noun *strain* as a verb and applies this to the piano music (which is what Debussy's "Clare du Lune" is) that the blind Marie hears in the room *over* her. the

The author could have written

> ...and then her grandfather’s song, “Clair de Lune,” *plays*  or *sounds* over her like a blue mist.

This 'over' could be strictly literal, since the gramophone is in the room (I think it's actually the attic or garret) over or above her grandfather’s bedroom.

'Over' could also be used metaphorically, similar to *The music washed over me*; here it is *like a blue mist*.

Why a blue mist? Debussy's "Clare du Lune" is a very evocative piano piece, one that is true art, in that it causes a lot of responses in most people who listen to it. Hear it at, among others, [this recording](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=-LXl4y6D-QI) and read some of the many among 9000+ comments about 'what the song evokes in or to  me'. One thing the song can evoke is the image of a blue mist.

"Clare du Lune" means, in French, "moonlight", and that word alone can call up images of light through a dark blue sky; you simply have to add some mist to get some blue mist.

A search of the available text to the novel on Google Books shows us that this is the third or fourth mention of the song  "Clare du Lune" in the novel.

Besides the connection with the song's meaning of "moonlight" with the book's title, it's also important to note that the author tries hard to  use descriptive language, including verbs, when describing the strains (sound) of this evocative piano piece. Elsewhere in the novel he talks about the piece thusly:

> a song that makes her think of leaves fluttering and of the hard ribbons of sand beneath her feet at low tide. The music slinks and rises and settles back to earth.

Note that mist might also be thought to slink and rise and settle back to earth.

And also

> Chords float past in transparent riffles.

So with

> ...and then her grandfather’s song, “Clair de Lune,” *strains* over her like a blue mist.

the author's just using a noun as a verb to describe the sound that the piano makes 'over her'. Or he's using an obsolete sense of *strain*. But even this obsolete usage displays a close connection between the noun and verb forms.

---

As [mentioned by Damkerng](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89618/the-meaning-of-verb-strain/89864?noredirect=1#comment174294_89864) there  is the obsolete meaning of *strain* as a verb to refer to singing or the playing of an instrument. But obsolete means "no longer used." So either the author decided to employ this obsolete usage or he  used the modern noun in a creative he way as a verb. I imagine that 99% of contemporary native speakers are unfamiliar with this obsolete usage. (That's why it's marked as obsolete in the *Oxford English Dictionary* or OED.)

There are many many words in English that are both nouns and verbs, so it's not surprising that there is an obsolete version of *strain* to refer to the sounding/playing of an instrument, including the human voice. Also, the OED hints that even the obsolete meaning probably was influenced by the noun forms.

To  me,  *strains* as a verb would work much better with violin music, since (a) the strings of a violin produce actual physical strain or tension on the violin; and (b) the unique sound of  violin music is often referred to as *strains*. I just don't see "strain" working very well with piano music, especially one that, to me, is pretty free of strain (in the sense of tension or something that puts a constraint on people). And to say that something *strains over someone like a mist* is, in my opinion,  not the greatest simile.

Comment: I just found this obsolete sense of *strain*, the verb, in OED1: V. 22. a. *trans.* To use (the voice) in song ; to play upon (an instrument). b. To utter in song. c. *intr.* To sing. *Obs.*

Comment: That doesn't surprise me at all @DamkerngT, although I don't see it in my online OED. I still say it works better for a violin. And who knows whether the author knew of this old usage or got a bit creative.

Comment: But it was a surprise to me! See, I was trying to find a sense of *strain* that's close to the use in the book, and when I found one, your answer just came in and it's good and all! So I couldn't do anything but post the definition in my short comment and upvote your answer! :-)

Answer (score 4):

The key may be in the name "Clair de Lune", French for "light of the moon". This is a name of several songs, poems and classical music pieces, and notably [Claude Debussy's piece](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIsQPdC9YnY) which the book refers to. The "blue mist" simile is clearly related to this name.

According to [Merriam-Webster's dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strain), one of the meanings of "strain" is "tune, air, a passage of verbal or musical expression". This meaning of "strain" is a noun, not a verb, but writers often apply "poetic license" and use words in uncommon ways.

Another meaning is, as other answers noted, related to pouring and filtering, which (understandably) reminds you of oozing and engulfing. The author could have used "pours" instead of "strains", but that wouldn't have that hint of music, and would be much less "magical".

This looks like an intentional (and clever) word-play by the author, who uses the multiple meanings of one word to induce a certain "fairy-like" and musical air, beyond the straightforward interpretation of the text.

Comment: The novel identifies this "Clare du Lune" as Debussy's.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that's the one but wasn't sure. I don't think I've read the book. Added a note to the answer.

Comment: +1 for the answer. It shows how creative prose fiction can be. I think it also  shows that contemporary modern speakers aren't aware of the obsolete usage of *to strain* that @DamkerngT minions.

Comment: @AlanCarmack If I may ask, as I'm quite curious now, what did you mean by that *minions*? :-)

Comment: @DamkerngT. I meant *mentions*. [Swiftkey](https://swiftkey.com/en) thought otherwise.

Comment: I see! (For a sec, I thought you might've used *minions* creatively. :P Then I gave up the idea and thought it'd be better to ask you. :-) Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Good answer! I wanted to add that reading the passage I definitely thought of "strains" like pouring into a strainer, and how if you pour a pot of something into a strainer the water comes out of the bottom in separate little streams, almost like rain, but more continuous. So to me the sentence kind of says "The music rained down over her"

Answer (score 0):

[strain](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strain) can be used as a noun about music, but none of the verbal uses are appropriate- separating liquids from solids, appliying pressure to something, causing resources (especially money) to be used.

The expression **blue mist** is also rather suspect: whereas **red mist** has clear connotations (anger), there is no such connotation for blue mist. It is the name of a brand of tobacco and a type of flower.

It is probably best to treat the whole clause as [purple prose](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purple_prose) and not try to examine the meaning literally.

Answer (score 0):

I think the definition of '**strain**', in this context will be:

> to pour or pass (a substance) or (of a substance) to be poured or passed through a sieve, filter, or strainer

Here, the substance, though used metaphorically, is the "**blue mist**". We all know that no sieve or filter is fine enough to hinder mist. Maybe the author meant that the song sung by her grandfather went through her (Again, metaphorically) like mist through a sieve. This may mean that she understood nothing from her grandfather's song, maybe it's the language or what he implied by singing that song.